# OC4J 10.1.3.1 - Failed to look up JNDI Location

Tags: oracle10g, oc4j

I am using OC4J 10.1.3.1. (It can be accessed via http://localhost/em)
A connection pool is created.

A DataSource is created.

In my servlet, I initiate jndiContext with parameters:
jndiFactory=oracle.j2ee.rmi.RMIInitialContextFactory
jndiUri=opmn://localhost:6003/home/default
jndiUsername=oc4jadmin
jndiPassword=ds12345

BUT, according to the log, it can connect to JNDI service and it CANNOT lookup "jdbc/ABCDataSource" successfully

Is there anything that I need to double check ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed. Thanks.

I used.

com.evermind.server.ApplicationInitialContextFactory

ormi://localhost

Thanks All